# Number of 5 element subsets of which $4$ are in geometric progression

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S=\{2^1,2^2 \ldots 2^{120}\}$. Determine the number of $5$ element subsets of $S$ each if which contains **exactly**$4$ terms which are in geometric Progression.

Here is my method:
Total possible subsets=no of possible 4 element subsets which are AP(5th element could be anything other than those 4 elements)-no. of possible 5 element subsets which are in AP

To solve possible 4 element subsets which are in AP and 5th number could be anything other than those elements
we will count the equations:
with d=1(common difference), number of ways to pick 4 elements from S is:
(1,2,3,4),(2,3,4,5),...(116,117,118,119),(117,118,119,120)
So a total of 117(=120-3d) ways.
no. of ways to choose fifth entry is  120-4=116
no of ways of choosing=117*116=13572

with d=2, number of ways to pick 4 elements from S is:
(1,3,5,7),(2,4,6,8),...(113,115,117,119),(114,116,118,120)
So a total of 114(=120-3*2) ways.
no. of ways to choose fifth entry is  120-4=116
no of ways of choosing=114*116=13224

with d=3, number of ways to pick 4 elements from S is:
(1,4,7,10),(2,5,8,11),...(110,113,116,119),(111,114,117,120)
So a total of 111(=120-3*3) ways.
no. of ways to choose fifth entry is  116
no of ways of choosing=111*116=12876

As we can see values are in AP...13572,13224,12876,....
common difference=13224-13572=348
Find maximum d possible:
(1,d+1,2d+1,3d+1): 3d+1=120, d=39.667=39
for d=39:
for(1,40,79,118),(2,41,80,119),(3,42,81,120) are possible. 
for(1,40,79,118): no. fifth entries possible is 120-4=116
no of ways choosing=3*116=348

Number of solutions=n/2(a+l), (formula for sum of AP)
=39(13572+348)/2=271440

To calculate 5 element subsets which are in AP:
similarly calculate for d=1,2,..
for d=1,maximum possible is (116,117,118,119,120): 116
for d=2,maximum possible is (112,114,116,118,120): 112
and so on
Sum of these sequence is=116+112+...+0
number of terms=0=116-(n-1)4, n=30
No of 5 element subsets is: 30(116+0)/2=1740

No. of possible 4 element subsets which are AP and fifth element not in AP
=271440-1740=269700.

I would like to know if it is correct. Am I missing something. Is my method OK? Thanks.

Comment: The question does not seem to be clear. Meanwhile, first reduce the problem to finding the number of $5$ element subsets of which $4$ are in arithmetic progression in $\{1,2,3,\cdots 120\}$.

Comment: I think it should be exactly $4$ terms.

Comment: @GyuminRoh  Could you still post a solution. I am not getting it.

Comment: I'm going to sleep (it is like 2 AM here) & I probably can't post tomorrow. Sorry :(